# how do I install Aptana Studio 3 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, aptana-studio

I'm trying to install Aptana Studio 3 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
and would like to know the best possible way to do so.

Comment: Why do you want to install it as standalone? Go for eclipse plugin version rather.

Comment: is it in umake?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how I got it done.

First thing to do is to download [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download).  Make sure that you download the right file for your architecture, 64bit or 32bit.  Once downloaded, make sure that the prerequisites are installed, before installing Aptana Studio.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer    
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
```

With terminal still open, navigate to where you downloaded Aptana Studio, probably the Downloads folder, and run the following command(s):

For 64bit

```
sudo unzip Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.6.1.zip -d /opt
```

For 32bit

```
sudo unzip Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_3.6.1.zip -d /opt
```

At this point Aptana Studio is fully installed, but it will not appear in Dash.

<sup>Oracle Java installation compliments of [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)</sup>

In order to get the Aptana Launcher icon and make it show-up in dash, create the following .desktop file with the following text in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Aptana Studio 3
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
Comment=Aptana Strudio 3 Integrated Development Environment
Exec=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3 %F
TryExec=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
Icon=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/icon.xpm
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass="Aptana Studio 3"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/x-javascript;application/x-php;application/x-java;text/x-javascript;text/html;text/plain
Categories=GNOME;Development;IDE;
```

And save it to `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: I'm want to use Oracle Java JDK. Will this affect your version of installation?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect using Oracle Java.

Comment: Hello Mitch, I followed your instructions; however, I'm unable to load Aptana Studio via Dash.

Comment: See added info in the answer.  I've added that.

Comment: @Mitch How do i create a desktop file, I have permission problem saving to that location. /usr/share/applications

Comment: Use `sudo` example:  sudo nano <file_name>.

Comment: Thanks Mitch! @Olaitan Mayowa: use this command: **sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/aptana.desktop**