# How can i change a file permision to "execute like a program"?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, aptana-studio

I want to install aptana studio, with the terminal, but, to install it, I need to execute the .zip, so, how can I change the permissions ? ( if it is possible with the terminal please )

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/554464/how-do-i-install-aptana-studio-3-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to "start" the archive: you want to unpack it! To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
unzip <your_zip>
```

---

To make a file executable use `chmod`:

```
chmod +x <your_file>
```

and start it with this command if you're in the same folder:

```
./<your_file>
```