# IDE with highlighting function?

Tags: software-recommendation

Can anyone advice IDE for [web-]development which can highlight all classes and function (at tree) automatically.

Cheerz!

Comment: PHP? Java? Perl? Python? CSS? HTML?...

Comment: I can recommend [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) or [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm). Both of them have a 30-day-trial.

Comment: what do you mean highlight all classes and function ? anyway, I guess any decent IDE will do, so pick your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)

Highlighting HTML:

[image]

Highlighting for PHP:

[image]

Highlighting Javascript:

[image]

Highlighting CSS:

[image]

Now inorder to install it in Ubuntu please refer to [how do I install Aptana Studio 3 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554464/how-do-i-install-aptana-studio-3-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Else if you still using 12.04 you can check [this](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/)