# Aptana Studio 3 Installation using apt-get?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, aptana-studio

I have done a web search on how to install [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/) in Ubuntu-Studio. What I was hoping for was a way to do it using apt-get so that it would be included in apt-get update. All I found instead was a complicated sequence of commands that does it. Also, I looked for it in the Software menu item. A search for Aptana there did not get a hit.

Is there a way to install Aptana Studio 3 so that it would be included in updates initiated by the command:

sudo apt-get update

Or the menu item:

System => Software Updater

?

Comment: Not that I'm aware off.  But take a look [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/554464/how-do-i-install-aptana-studio-3-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts), for installation instructions.

Comment: In MS Windows all that is ever needed to install software is to click on an .msi file, or execute an .exe file. Until the day it is just as easy to install all software in Ubuntu, or any Linux based OS, Ubuntu and those other Linux versions, will be only for geeks. I am capable of following those directions. There a many I know who either cannot, or won’t bother. I for one am abandoning MS Windows due to privacy issues raised by Microsoft’s telemetry.

Comment: in all fairness, IDE's are different from most software.  But, I feel your pain.