# How to Install Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: software-installation, aptana-studio

I installed Aptana Studio 3 tonight... But something went wrong. The IDE does not have a launcher icon and I can't run it from a terminal. I am using Ubuntu 19.04.

I followed [a tutorial from the web](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/03/22/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-19-04-disco/), but the tutorial is difficult to understand. Please, if possible, I need a complete tutorial teaching how to complete uninstall it and reinstall it.

I noticed that in the tutorial the name of the zip to unzip is different from the zip pack I downloaded. So I changed the name and it works. But the code to make a symlink does not work. So I simply cannot make the IDE work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I install Aptana Studio 3 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554464/how-do-i-install-aptana-studio-3-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: The link is this: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/03/22/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-19-04-disco/. I noticed that in the tutorial the name of the zip to unzip is different from the zip pack i downloaded. So i change the name and it works. But the code to make a Symlink does not work. So i simple can not make the IDE work... I hope someone can help me here. Thank you all.

Comment: @ErickBianchini I added an answer below with the easiest way I could think of. Please try it and let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to have **Aptana Studio 3** up and running on Ubuntu in no time.

---

**Firstly:** Install the required JAVA version `openjdk-8-jdk` and set it as default by following the instructions below:

- To install `openjdk-8-jdk`, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

- To set `openjdk-8-jdk` as default, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will see an output like this:

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1411      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1411      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Please, enter the number in front of `java-8-openjdk` under `Selection` column and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

**Secondly**: download, extract and set permissions for **Aptana Studio 3** by following the instructions below:

1. Please download the latest `aptana.studio-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip` from [here](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/releases) and place it in your home directory or wherever you want.
2. Please right click on the downloaded `aptana.studio-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip` file and extract it by choosing **Extract Here**. You will then have a new directory with the extracted **Aptana Studio 3** in it like in the image below:

[image]

> You will need `unzip` to extract the file. If it is not installed,
>   please install it by running the following command in the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install unzip
> ```

3. Please double click on the newly extracted directory to open it.
4. Once inside the directory, please find the `AptanaStudio3` file and right click on it and select **properties**.
5. Please, select the **Permissions** tab and put a check mark next to **Execute** like in the image below:

[image]

---

**Finally:** Double click on the `AptanaStudio3` file to run **Aptana Studio 3** and enjoy.