# Can I install two versions of Java?

Tags: java

I have installed Java 11 on my pc, but one app doesn't work with that version.

Is there any way to install an additional version of Java?

Comment: You should probably add which version of Ubuntu you're using. This may somewhat impact the answers :)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1168094/968501

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I need JDK 11 for Android Studio and JRE 8 for Thinkorswim.
I haven't found a way that works automatically but a quick manual fix is to run the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Then select the version you need and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, following the onscreen instructions.
It works the same even if you need to change `javac`.

Here are the links that provided this solution:
[Install Oracle JDK 11 on Linux - Java Helps](https://www.javahelps.com/2017/09/install-oracle-jdk-9-on-linux.html)
and
[Learning Center - Technical](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/faq/technical#q_011111111111111114)

Comment: thanks a lot sir, this work for me.